# Explorar recursivamente una carpeta

Tags: python, spyder

Necesito crear una función recursiva que cuando encuentre un directorio, se llame recursivamente para explorarlo, es decir necesito mostrar por pantalla los archivos y las subcarpetas dentro de esta  carpeta. 
pd : Necesito hacer uso de **for entry in os.scandir(ruta)** y **os.path.join**

```
import os

def explorar(basedir):

    ruta='carpeta'
    for entry in os.scandir(ruta):

        print(entry.name, entry.is_file(), entry.is_dir())

        rutac = os.path.join(ruta, 'carpeta')
        print(rutac)
```

Comment: Necesita explorar todo el aŕbol de directorios y subdirectorios pero ¿necesitas que la función se implemente usando recursión o iterativamente (for y algun contenedor que actue de cola)?

Comment: usando recursion

Answer (score 0):

Basta con usar `os.DirEntry.is_dir` y en caso de ser un directorio llamar recursivamente a la función:

```
import os

def explorar(basedir):
    with os.scandir(basedir) as it:
        for entry in it:
            print(entry.path)
            if entry.is_dir():
                explorar(entry)
```

Si quieres siempre la ruta absoluta, puedes usar `os.path.abspath`:

```
def explorar(basedir):
    base_path = os.path.abspath(basedir)
    with os.scandir(base_path) as it:
        for entry in it:
            print(entry.path)
            if entry.is_dir():
                explorar(entry)
```

No termino de ver la necesidad de usar `os.path.join`, el atributo `os.DirEntry.path` es equivalente a `os.path.join(base_path, entry.name)`

Comment: Son unos ejercicios de clase y tengo que usar esos atributos

Comment: Tengo que hacer uso de : 

    ruta='carpeta'
    for entry in os.scandir(ruta):
        print(entry.name, entry.is_file(), entry.is_dir())

Comment: ¿Y que es "carpeta"? El usar `with` o no puedes quitarlo y usar `for entry in os.scandir(ruta):`, es una mala practica no cerrar el iterador, pero bueno.... Imprimir print(entry.name, entry.is_file(), entry.is_dir()) no es problema, cambialo por el print que uso..

Comment: 'carpeta' es el nombre de la carpeta que quiero ver los archivos / subcarpetas que hay dentro

Comment: Es decir, el valor de basedir inicial...

Comment: Si es la carpeta inicial

Comment: Si el valor de `ruta` no quieres que cambie entre llamadas (siempre es la ruta de partida), vas a necesitar pasar dos argumentos a la función... Si puede cambiar entre llamadas, entonces es basedir sin más... Es complicarse mucho la vida sin sentido para hacer algo más ineficiente y enrevesado a conciencia, pero bueno... :)

Comment: La funcion solo recibe un parametro basedir . Si te endtiendo de que es mas enrevesado pero me lo han mandado asi :(

Comment: Algo falla, es imposible hacer que ruta sea  siempre el directorio de partida a no ser que sea una variable global lo cual no tiene sentido.... Si la variable ruta depende de basedir, ruta cambiará en cada llamada porque  basedir tiene que cambiar en cada llamada o no podremos hacer la función recursiva....  Además en esa caso ruta y basedir son lo mismo la ruta a la carpeta a escanear ene esa llamada... ¿Tienes enunciado o algo?

Comment: implementar la funcion recursiva explorar que, cuando encuentre un directorio, se llame recursivamente para explorarlo. La salida que debe generar tu programa para el resultado de descomprimir el fichero carpeta.zip.

Comment: Nos dan esto :  def explorar(basedir):
    
    ruta='carpeta' 
    for entry in os.scandir(ruta):
        print(entry.name, entry.is_file(), entry.is_dir())